# Postgres: Conditional statement in with clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, bulkinsert

I am trying to migrate Oracle to Postgres.
Wherever in Oracle we have bulk collect function, I have created plain SQL function:
like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pub_access_tax(a_person_id mobile_user.id%TYPE)
RETURNS TABLE (tax_id integer) AS 
$$
    WITH v_pub_tax AS (SELECT tax_id FROM mobile_pub_tax)
    select tax_id from v_pub_tax ;

$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

But there is a scenario in Oracle where data are fetched on conditional basis: (see below example)

```
  FUNCTION get_st_tax(
    a_st_type IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN mmt_array
  IS
   v_tax_list  mmt_array := mmt_array();
  BEGIN
    IF a_st_type = 'top-stories' THEN
      SELECT t.tax_id BULK COLLECT INTO v_tax_list
      FROM mobile_st_tax t;
      RETURN v_tax_list;
    ELSE
      SELECT t.tax_id BULK COLLECT INTO v_tax_list
      FROM mobile_st_tax t WHERE t.stream_type=a_stream_type;
      RETURN v_tax_list;
    END IF;
  END;
```

How can we convert above Oracle code to Postgres?

I tried using if condition but getting syntax error(below code). 
Below code I have tried executing in Postgres, which gives me syntax error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_st_tax ( a_st_type IN VARCHAR) 
RETURNS TABLE (tax_id integer) AS 
$$  
    IF a_stream_type = 'top-stories' THEN
        WITH v_tax_list AS (
        SELECT t.tax_id FROM mobile_st_tax t)
        SELECT tax_id FROM v_tax_list;
    ELSE
        WITH v_tax_list AS (
        SELECT t.tax_id FROM mobile_st_tax t WHERE t.stream_type=a_stream_type)
        SELECT tax_id FROM v_tax_list;   
    END IF;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you post your PostgreSQL version of second function and what error it gives? From what I can see there shouldn't be any issue with this, other than there is no equivalent (that I know of) for `bulk collect` in pg.

Comment: Below code I have tried executing in Postgres, which gives me syntax error.
 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_st_tax ( a_st_type IN VARCHAR) 
RETURNS TABLE (tax_id integer) AS 
$$  
 IF a_stream_type = 'top-stories' THEN
  WITH v_tax_list AS (
  SELECT t.tax_id FROM mobile_st_tax t)
  SELECT tax_id FROM v_tax_list;
 ELSE
  WITH v_tax_list AS (
  SELECT t.tax_id FROM mobile_st_tax t WHERE t.stream_type=a_stream_type)
  SELECT tax_id FROM v_tax_list;   
    END IF;
 
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function can be done in plain sql:

```
create function get_st_tax(a_st_type text)
returns int[] as $$
    select array_agg(t.tax_id)
    from mobile_st_tax t 
    where 
        t.stream_type = a_stream_type and a_st_type <> 'top_stories'
        or
        a_st_type = 'top-stories'
    ;
$$ language sql;
```